# Lightswitch: Set focus to cell in datagrid

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

In code I add a new record to a Lightswitch grid in a list-details screen.  How can I set focus (place cursor) in third column of bottom row (record just added)?

```
public partial class JobsBudgetListDetail
{
      static DataGrid budgetGrid;
      partial void JobBudgetsAddNew_Execute()
{
      int jobID = Jobs.SelectedItem.JobID;
      int maxLineNo = 0;
      if (Jobs.SelectedItem.JobBudgets.Count() > 0)
            maxLineNo = this.DataWorkspace.ContractorData.JobBudgetsByDescLineNoForGivenJobID(jobID).FirstOrDefault().BudgetLineNo;

      JobBudget newBudget = this.DataWorkspace.ContractorData.JobBudgets.AddNew();
      newBudget.BudgetDate = this.propertyBudgetDate;
      newBudget.BudgetLineNo = maxLineNo + 10;
      newBudget.Job = Jobs.SelectedItem;
      Microsoft.LightSwitch.Threading.Dispatchers.Main.BeginInvoke(() =>
      {
            // next line selects the row just added
            budgetGrid.SelectedIndex = JobBudgets.Count - 1;                    
            // now, how set focus to column 3 on this row?
      });
 }
```

Comment: does setting the [DataGrid.CurrentColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.currentcolumn%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) property work?

Answer (score 1):

jberger is right but I wasn't sure of the syntax.  After looking at some Silverlight sites, I found that this works:

```
    budgetGrid.CurrentColumn = budgetGrid.Columns[2];
```

Pretty simple in retrospect!

Comment: The .Columns[2] syntax highlights cell but still requires clicking in it to start typing.  any ideas?